# Plugins in WP_Options but not Active

Tags: plugins, database

Just completed a WordPress host migration. I had to disable plugins by deleting them in the WP_Options table. I have just added the correct plugins back into the db. However, the plugins are not active on the page.

My question is, what do I need to do now to activate the plugins so that they are in working order on the page again?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: modifying the DB directly is a great way to corrupt your data (as you probably done here). This should be extreme last resort.

Comment: How would I corrupt my data? You simply back up your data and then make your modifications. Data corruption is a result of careless actions.

Comment: cool, then you just lost time. if pointlessly restoring backups makes you happy then there is no problem with your method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you will need to activate the plugins on the plugins page.

A side note:

For future reference if you need to disable plugins during a migration. Don't migrate the plugins across and wordpress will automatically disable them. Then you would copy them to the plugins folder and active as usual. This would also keep all the settings set prior to the migration.

Comment: Ya this worked. I also found that there were a lot of unused plugins activated on the site, which was killing load times.